# Ubuntu 18.4 maas node commissioning fails lldpd

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, maas

I have configured maas region&rack controller in virtualbox and adding a node via PXE. PXE boot works fine and the node is being set up. However, when I try to commission the node, two of the steps fail.
[image]

00-maas-03-install-lldpd

```
Reading package lists...

Building dependency tree...

Reading state information...
```

E: Unable to locate package lldpd

99-maas-02-capture-lldp

```
Reading package lists...

Building dependency tree...

Reading state information...

E: Unable to locate package lldpd
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue and problem was with connection to apt repos from commissioning node (I know that it sounds weird but other steps doesn't need updating and install packages from repositories). In my case the problem was with firewall **ufw**, maas proxy port was blocked.

```
sudo ufw allow 8000
```

*Other ports that also should be accepted 5240, 5248, 69, 514.*

Other fixes that I find when digging into that problem.

If you have an IPv6 interface squid tries to resolve DNS via IPv6 so you can change priority by modifying config

```
sudo nano /var/lib/maas/maas-proxy.conf
```

add line

```
dns_v4_first on
```

and restart service

```
sudo service maas-proxy stop
sudo service maas-proxy start
```

You can try not to use maas proxy at all (but in this case your network for commissioning nodes should have internet access, via maas NAT or other gw)

**Settings -> Network Services -> Proxy -> "Don't use a proxy" -> save**